# What does HAMP mean, computer fan context?

Tags: fan

I'm using the Asus [X99-DELUXE-II](https://www.asus.com/us/Motherboards/X99-DELUXE-II/) motherboard:

[image]

Answer (score 22, accepted):

It stands for High Amperage Fan. There should be a header (pins) on the board for you to plug in multiple fans or fans that are higher current. H-Amp fans usually have better cooling.

The manual setting for that board would allow you to set measure points and min/max temperatures, etc.

Search "High AMP" at this Asus page:
https://www.asus.com/us/Motherboards/ROG-RAMPAGE-V-EDITION-10/

Comment: Is a HAMP port compatible with normal-amp fans, or does it require a HAMP fan/controller?

Answer (score 13):

It is **H**igh **AMP**erage header connection for a fan on Asus motherboards, which can provide up to 3 A for powerful fans.